# Как задать направление тора(пончика)?

Tags: математика

Формула тора:

```
(x**2 + y**2 + z**2 + R**2 - r**2)**2 - 4*(R**2)*(x**2 + y**2)=0
```

Так можно задать тор и расположение его центральной точки:

```
((a - x)**2 + (b - y)**2 + (c - z)**2 + R**2 - r**2)**2 - 4*(R**2)*((a - x)**2 + (b - y)**2) = 0
```

где:
a, b, c = (x, y, z) # центральная точка
А как задать вращение, относительно центральной точки, зная вектор в который он будет направлен.

Comment: Концептуально, все довольно просто - нужно подставить в это неявное уравнение вместо {X, Y, Z} результат перемножения матрицы поворота на вектор {x, y, z} системы координат, в которой вы хотите видеть повернутый тор.

О том, как составить матрицу поворота, можно ознакомиться в Википедии.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Общая формула поворота

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то для поворота x нужно заменить на x'

```
x' =   x * cos(a)cos(в)
     + y * (cos(a)sin(в)sin(г)-sin(а)cos(г))
     + z * (cos(а)sin(в)cos(г)+sin(а)sin(г))
```

и так далее. Если это нужно в компьютерной программе, то лучше оставить все изменения в 3х матрицах и умножать через numpy или простую функцию

В матрице поворота также можно сделать смещение заменив нули в столбце на нужную величину и масштабировать - сжимать/растягивать умножив коэфиценты